# sys.stdout not reassigning to sys.__stdout__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python so I am still just learning the language. One of the things I came across was reassigning sys.stdout to change the default output of print. So I wrote this as a test:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('log.txt','a')
print('hey')
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print('hi')
```

'Hey' is written to the file, but 'hi' shows up nowhere. However, this works as expected, and 'hey' is written to the file, and 'hi' is printed to the console output:

```
import sys
sys.__stdout__ = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(r'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\Python\log.txt','a')
print('hey')
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print('hi')
```

In short its a small problem that doesnt really matter too much, I am just wondering if there's a discernible reason why its not working the way it should. I have tried this on Windows 7 Home Premium with IDLE and pyscripter on v3.2.3 and my portable python v3.2.1.

Comment: How do you run this script? You didn't tell if the first `print` worked or not. *When I assign some other variable to sys.stdout in the beginning and change it back it works* It would be better to write code illustrating this and describe it's output.

Answer (score 7):

In IDLE, `sys.__stdout__` is the program's original standard output - which goes nowhere, since it's not a console application.  In other words, IDLE itself has already replaced `sys.stdout` with something else (its own console window), so you're taking two steps backwards by replacing your own `stdout` with `__stdout__`.

Answer (score 3):

I would try this workaround (not using `sys.__stdout__` at all because your environment could have made both `sys.stdout` and `sys.__stdout__` distinct):

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('log.txt','a')
print('hey')
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

backuping the reference of `sys.stdout` seems the safest way to do it. Worked in another slightly different case: [stdout redirect from Jupyter notebook is landing in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200375/stdout-redirect-from-jupyter-notebook-is-landing-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a context manager that backups the old states of `sys.std<in|out|err>` for you, as a complement to the other answers.

Personally, I use it with my programs based on PyQt5 where the standard output is redirected towards a text-based widget as long as the app is running. The output is redirected back to my IDE's console once the app is closed.

```
import sys

class SysStdRedirection:
    """Any change done to `sys.std<in|out|err>` inside this context manager will
       be reverted upon exit."""

    def __init__(self):
        for x in ("stdin", "stdout", "stderr"):
            setattr(self, x, getattr(sys, x))

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, error_type=None, value=None, traceback=None):
        for x in ("stdin", "stdout", "stderr"):
            setattr(sys, x, getattr(self, x))
```

Usage:

```
with SysStdRedirection():
    sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'a')
    print('hey')
    sys.stdout.close()
print('hi')
```