# stdout redirect from Jupyter notebook is landing in the terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

So I was trying to redirect `stdout` for a some of the cells in my Jupyter Notebook to a file with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python#4675744) and then cancel it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245227/python-reset-stdout-to-normal-after-previously-redirecting-it-to-a-file) for the rest of the cells. The output from the first set of cells landed in the file like it was meant to. The second set of cells after the cancel command `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` was giving no output, appearing to do nothing, but I later realised it was landing in the terminal where the notebook was launched.

It works perfectly in the Python interpreter with exactly the same Python:

```
(miniconda3-latest) cardamom@pegasus:~/Documents/project1 $ python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = open('stdout.txt', 'w')
>>> print("a")
>>> print("a")
>>> print("a")
>>> sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
>>> print ("b")
b
>>> print ("b")
b
>>> print ("b")
b
>>> # lots of a's are in the file and no b's
```

A similar approach in the Jupyter notebook is giving this in the terminal:

```
[W 22:05:34.192 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js (127.0.0.1) 1.71ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/test_stdout.ipynb
b
b
b
```

How can this code be adapted so that after resetting it, I get the b's appearing under the cells where the output usually goes instead of in the terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only explanation I see is that `sys.stdout` is *not* `sys.__stdout__` but a rerouted/modified file object in order to be able to put data in cells (your comment indicates that it's a `ipykernel.iostream.OutStream` instance).

So instead of resetting to `sys.__stdout__`, you should store the reference of `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('stdout.txt', 'w')
...
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Note that this method also works with a standard terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Never thought it was something you could backup but when I look at the object for `old_stdout` in the notebook it looks like this: `<ipykernel.iostream.OutStream at 0x7f71eeae6c50>`

Comment: I must admit that I didn't even notice that `sys.__stdout__` even existed. I always used the method described in my answer (must be used to languages like C where everything must be done by hand :)). Note that you're not backuping, it, you're just storing the _reference_ instead of losing it.

Comment: The problem comes when your program is aborted. Jupyter remembers the state of stdout, and it can't be recovered without a kernel restart. This is inconvenient. Is there some other way to reset the stdout to redirect to the Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

To handle your case of aborted execution, you could try to handle the error.

```
import sys
nb_stdout = sys.stdout
with open("cell_output.deleteme", 'w') as cl_stdout:
    sys.stdout = cl_stdout
    try:
        print("hello, world!")
        raise Exception("goodbye, cruel world!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        print("cell stdout")
        sys.stdout = nb_stdout
        print("notebook stdout")
```