# Recover cell outputs from a running kernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, jupyter, ipython

I have a notebook connecting to a remote Jupyter kernel. The remote connection was disconnected for some time. After reconnecting, the notebook did not get the cell outputs from the remote kernel. Is there a way to recover the cell's output from the remote kernel? The kernel is still running.

The outputs are using `print`, so I can't use the global variable `Out`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969937/reconnecting-remote-jupyter-notebook-and-get-current-cell-output).