# Can't print Python pyo

Tags: python, pyo

Help, I can't seem to print anything as soon as I call pyo audio server.

It just exits without returning anything.

Even something like this:

```
from pyo import *
s = Server()
print("this is not printed")
s.boot()
x = 3.4
print(x,"neither are these")
```

This should be working right? Or am I hugely mistaken?

I am using the python module `pyo` version 1.0.1
with Python version 3.7.3
run using Python IDLE 3.7

btw: audio output works, I just want printing for debugging purposes

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, what happens when you input this line by line in a REPL?

Comment: wow, it works when run in command prompt. Is this a IDLE problem

Comment: What OS? Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: windows 10, no, it is not able to print anything after the line "s = Server()"

Comment: I have reproduced this problem on Windows 10 using IDLE, Jupyter Notebook, and VS Code's Interactive Window - as soon as I run `s=Server()`, somehow the output of `print` **gets redirected to the shell that opened the GUI**.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be redirection of `stdout` as seen here: [stdout redirect from Jupyter notebook is landing in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45200375/5103770)

The example below worked for me.
I don't know whether this fix screws up anything with `pyo` - I imagine the GUI portion could have some issues - but I have been able to produce the sounds I want after applying this fix.

```py
# %%
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout

# %%
print('Hello World') # Outputs 'Hello World'

# %%
s=Server()
print('Hello Server') # No output; 'Hello Server' appears in the terminal that called python to begin with

# %%
sys.stdout = old_stdout
print('Hello Again') # Outputs 'Hello Again'
```